# Im getting error : need a singel repository as argument

Tags: mkusb

Im getting error : need a singel repository as argument
On 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa sudo apt install mkusb

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa;sudo apt install mkusb
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~mkusb/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~mkusb' user or team does not exist.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mkusb
it is giving me this

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon "`;`" to separate the two commands: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa; sudo apt install mkusb`. Otherwise, `add-apt-repository` thinks you want to add `ppa:mkusb/ppa`, `sudo`, `apt` , `install` and `mkusb`, the last 4 of which are not repositories.